# PDF Creation on iOS With Multiple Text Fields And Images

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, uiimageview

I am looking at building a simple PDF generator.  The user will have several text fields and a couple image fields to enter information, and that will appear in specific spots on the PDF.  I know how to add an image already in the app to the PDF, but not sure how to take an image that is chosen from Camera Roll on one view to be in the PDF on the next view.  Suggestions?